# npm unable to install dependencies

Tags: node.js, unix, terminal, npm

I'm trying to install some npm modules and all goes fine until I try to install the dependencies of the installed modules. npm shows this log:

```
$ sudo npm install -g
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install .
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open 'package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/roemerbakker
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! path package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/roemerbakker/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
$
```

Also tried the command without -g but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Does package.json exist in the folder you are running the command? If it does, can you open it in text editor and see the file is valid?

Comment: @alandarev just created one in ~/ but is that necessary if I just want to install the dependencies for global modules? And what does it have to say?

Comment: As @Charminbear said, you do not need to run npm install for installed packages.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for this. When you install a npm package with `npm install <package name>` (globally or locally), it already installs all of its dependencies on its own.

You only need the `npm install` command when you checked out an Application with a `package.json`-File to install the APPLICATIONS Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade ALL global packages, you should use:
npm update -g